# How to access an object from a callback function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-feed-api

I feel bad because it is very likely this has already been answered and I am just not using the right search terms.  I am very new to asynchronous JavaScript.  So, I will lead with an apology.  If someone could even just help me get the right search terms I would most appreciate it.

I am trying to use the Google feeds api.  I have it working when I follow the stock example as laid out in the hello world section.  I am trying to make something that is a little more extensible so that I can use it in several places.  So I created an object...

```
function AlertRSS(num, url, div, date) {
  this.num = typeof num !== 'undefined' ? num : 5;
  this.url = typeof url !== 'undefined' ? url : 'http://arstechnica.com/author/caseyjohnston/feed/';
  this.sel = typeof sel !== 'undefined' ? sel : '#alert';
  this.date = typeof date !== 'undefined' ? date : this.getYesterday();
}
```

I then try to call the object inside of the method...

```
AlertRSS.prototype.displayFeed = function() {
  var retval = null;
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(this.url);
  feed.load(function(result) {
  var tmp = this;
    if (!result.error) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        console.log(sel + ' <h2><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></h2><br  />');
        $(tmp.sel).append('<h2><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></h2><br  />');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

However, it seems like I am not able to access the properties from the object. I keep getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: sel is not defined` in the console.

I think the issue is related to scope, but at this point I feel a little out of my depth.  Any help would be most appreciated.

## Update

For a first post this was a travesty.  I had numerous mistakes in my code.  Both responses were correct.  However, in case another poor newb like me sees this question, I wanted to put working code out there.

The issue turned out to be placement of the `var tmp = this;` line.  It needs to be placed outside of the internal callback function to work.  As per Tomasz Nurkiewicz suggestion, I also changed `var tmp` to `var that`.  Working code is as follows:

```
function AlertRSS(num, url, sel, date) {
  this.num = typeof num !== 'undefined' ? num : 5;
  this.url = typeof url !== 'undefined' ? url : 'http://arstechnica.com/author/caseyjohnston/feed/';
  this.sel = typeof sel !== 'undefined' ? sel : '#alert';
  this.date = typeof date !== 'undefined' ? date : this.getYesterday();
}

AlertRSS.prototype.displayFeed = function() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(this.url);
  var that = this;
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        console.log(that.sel + ' <h2><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></h2><br  />');
        $(that.sel).append('<h2><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></h2><br  />');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly creating `tmp` variable to capture `this` (note that typically it is called `that` in this context). You are even correctly using this reference here: `tmp.sel`. However you forgot to use it in line before that:

```
console.log(sel + ' <h2><a href="' + entry.link + '">' + entry.title + '</a></h2><br  />');
```

Change to:

```
console.log(tmp.sel + //...
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: Tomasz, thank you for your help.  I made the change, and I am now getting...  `*undefined* <h2><a href="http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2012/06/angry-internet-lawyer-sues-the-oatmeal-bears-and-cancer-research/">Angry "Internet lawyer" sues The Oatmeal, bears, and cancer research</a></h2><br  />` I still think it might be a scope issue, but at least there is no more error!  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you again.  You got me on the right path.  I have posted the working code below.

Answer (score 1):

Your function params ask for div not sel.

Comment: Thank you! I did miss that parameter in the constructor when I refactored the code.